# Azure Appfabric Distribute Cache how it works

Tags: azure

I've been reading a bit on Azure Appfabric caching. From what I understand its a distributed cache.

However I'm bit confused with configuration below where there is not **host** node specified.

Could someone please clarify if the config below is still a distributed cache? If yes, how it's distributed given that the caching storage is located on Local Resource of each Instance?

```
 <dataCacheClients>
         <dataCacheClient name="default">
         </dataCacheClient>
     </dataCacheClients>

<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider"
         type="Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider,
Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache"
         cacheName="default"
         useBlobMode="true"
         dataCacheClientName="default" />
  </providers>

</sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the config you have above?  I'm wondering if it could be missing something in other configuration locations.

There are two types of Caching services in Windows Azure.  One used to be called AppFabric caching, but is now referred to simply as Windows Azure Shared Caching.  You'll want to avoid the older documentation around anything called AppFabric as they no longer use that name and the articles, docs and samples using it could be out of date.  The other option is Windows Azure Caching, and the only difference in the naming is the term "Shared".  Both options are distributed caches; however, what makes them different is where they distributed to and what features they support.  I'll start with Windows Azure Caching (the non-shared).

Windows Azure Caching is the relatively newer option and you may also see it called Role-based caching.  This version of the caching gives you a LOT more flexibility and features such as named caches, ability to detect items removal from cache, etc.  This option also has the benefit of not having limitations and quotas that could stop you from getting at your cache if you have a spike in your load.  In addition, you pay for the size of cache you want based on how you configure the role that is hosting the cache and in the end have a LOT more flexibility around your cache.  You configure this distributed cache to run on one of your roles within a Cloud Service deployment.  So, if you have a web role you can set it to run your website as well as host your distributed cache.  You can also have a dedicated worker role that does nothing more than be the host for your distributed cache.    Check out this article for capacity planning for this option: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914129.aspx.

Windows Azure Shared Caching is what used to be called AppFabric Caching and is a Shared service that you can plug into.  It is a distributed cache, with the data being hosted on Microsoft run instances in Windows Azure.  Because it is a shared service you can run into quotas and limitations that are in place simply so that one user of the service doesn't affect the others too greatly.  There are quotas on number of transaction, about of data, etc.  You pay for this service by the size of memory cache you use.  It can be painful to change the tier quickly (or at least there are rules around how quickly you can swap out tier sizes) and you lose a lot of flexibility that the newer option has.  Also, the cap is 4 GB of memory for quote a bit of cost.

Looking at the configuration you have provided I don't see the host option, which you pointed out, so this must be configuration from the non-shared version.  Only the shared caching version uses the hosts elements.  The non-shared version does some magic behind the scenes using the configuration provided in the CS Def and CS Config files to determine where the cluster is (and it must be within the same Cloud Service).  More detailed configuration docs can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914132.aspx  If this indeed the non shared version then the distribution is done across the number of instances of the role hosting the cache.  If you only have 1 instance, well, it's not very distributed.  If you increase the role count to 2 then the data gets distributed across both.  If you elect to have High Availability turned on in your configuration then replications of your data will be kept across the cluster and fault domains so that if one of the instances in the cluster goes away you still have copies of your data in cache. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914162.aspx).

Finally, if you are seeing some reference to local caching that might be in reference to where you can set up local storage for "local caching".  So, while the data is still stored in the distributed cache it can also pull a copy local to the instance.  This is good for metadata and lookups like lists of States, things that don't change pretty much at all.  This allows the local node to read from the local cache, but then go back to the larger distributed cache for the data it doesn't have or that expires locally.  I don't see where the config above references Local Storage Resources though, so not sure if you were crossing terms or have seen a reference outside of what you have provided here.